# How to copy file with Target Copy on file change

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj, msbuild-target

```
  <Target Name="BeforeCompile">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\Foo.js" DestinationFolder="Foo.Files\Js" SkipUnchangedFiles="True" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" />
  </Target>
```

This code running before build. But i want to do this when the file changes in debug. It's posible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "when this file changes" ? Since you use `SkipUnchangedFiles=True` the file already won't be copied unless it really changed.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the 'in debug'

Comment: Is SkipUnchangedFiles=True not working?  It should only copy when there is change in file.  Can you please explain your question in detail?

Comment: 'SkipUnchangedFiles=True' is working. But in this case i need to stop the project and run it again (for build). I want to be change js file in debug mode(without stopping the project).

Comment: You may want to look into hosting a webpack dev process in your application (debug configuration) to watch for js changes (see [JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/)). or run any js watch-based tool (grunt, gulp) from a console window while working on your project.

Comment: Are you asking if you can have the target file coped *only* when the project is set to `Debug` configuration?

Comment: I'm note sure if it will give you what but try this:
1. Give your target a different name `<Target Name="CopyTarget">` 
2. Add `CopyTarget` to the `InitialTargets` of the `Project` like `<Project ... InitialTargets="CopyTarget" ... >`.

I noticed that initial targets trigger virtually "all the time" in visual studio.

Comment: Alternatively, If you want something to monitor your files during runtime, you can use MSBuild to `<Exec Command=""/>` and run a secondary process which will monitor your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSBuild only runs to build your project.
While the executable is running, MSBuild is no longer working on your project.

This means that there is no possibility to do this (watch sources) in MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

I did using the Grunt([grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)).

[Grunt Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbfPW.png)
[Grunt Config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX8ES.png)

Thanks everyone...